# Cannot step into class after updating com.android.tools.build:gradle to 3.3.0 or 3.4.X

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have a simple class (KeyManagementViewModel) that has a reference to another of my classes (UserConfigRepository):

```
public class KeyManagementViewModel extends ViewModel {
private LiveData<ErrorWrapper<UserConfig>> userConfig;
private UserConfigRepository repo;

public LiveData<ErrorWrapper<UserConfig>> getUserConfig() {
    if (userConfig == null) {
        repo = new UserConfigRepository(userId); //BREAKPOINT HERE
        userConfig = repo.getUserConfigLive(); //CAN'T RESOLVE "repo" here
    }

    return userConfig;
}
}
```

In my project build.gradle i have

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }

  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1' //CAN'T BE UPGRADED
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.29.0'
  }
}
```

With this configuration, I can put a breakpoint in `KeyManagementViewModel.getUserConfig` in the line i commented and everything works fine if I step into the repo's `getUserConfigLive`. However, **when I update com.android.tools.build:gradle to 3.3.0 or 3.4.2**, now the breakpoint works as before, but if i step into the repo's `getUserConfigLive()`, i don't see the source code of my class and any breakpoint inside the repo class is never hit. I know the code is being executed because my logs in the repo class still appear in the console. Something else i notice is that if i break in the line *after* my "BREAKPOINT HERE" comment, it says "repo=No such instance field:'repo'" even though `repo` it was instantiated in the line before. It's as if the debugger is in a weird state where it doesn't recognize my Repo class or the current state. Here is the stacktrace after stepping into `getUserConfigLive()`, showing that it doesn't recognize the repo class as my own or the fields as valid. Any idea what causes this or how to fix it? I have the same problem in IntellJ Idea latest and Android Studio latest. I'm using Gradle 5.1.1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was the new R8 shrinker introduced in the gradle plugin 3.3.0
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#behavior-changes

For some reason, R8 was obfuscating my `UserConfigRepository` class whereas Proguard was not. This is not a long term solution but disabling minification is a good test. My long term solution was increasing the `minSdkVersion` to 21 so I get the new [implicit multidex support](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-on-l) and was allowed to disable minification in debug applications, which is the recommended way anyway